# Classifier using two distributions

Tags: machine-learning, probability, estimation

I'v asked this question on the Mathematica exchange [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128897/classifier-from-two-distributions) but looking for more formal/rigorous answer.

Suppose I have two classes {class1, class2} and have their associated distributions, pdf1(x) and pdf2(x).

Then, given an x value, what is the appropriate (statistically optimal) way to classify x ?

I feel like there should be some kind of Kalman or Bayesian formalism in optimal estimation to do this in a way which would/should generalize to N classes.

Similar questions [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8573/bayes-classifier-of-two-normal-distributions-in-matlab) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44717/combining-results-of-two-classifiers-to-better-classify-a-data-point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumptions that the prior probabilities for the classes are the same, the costs of misclassifications are the same and the the class conditional pdfs are completely known, assign an unlabelled observation $x_{0}$ into  class1, if $$pdf1(x_{0})>pdf2(x_{0})$$.

If there are $N$ classes, assign an unlabelled observation $x_{0}$ into  $class_k$, if $$pdf_k(x_{0}) = max\{pdf_{j}(x_{0}),\;j=1,2,,\cdots,N\}$$.
under similar assumptions as in the two population case.

This rule ifs known as Maximum Likelihood classification rule.

Comment: What if assumptions one and two are removed/relaxed?  That is, prior probabilities for the classes are not equal and do not have same utility.

Comment: If prior probs for the classes are known, we choose the largest posterior probs $P(class_{i}|x_{0})$, for i=1,2.  Classify $x_{0}$ to $class_{1}$, if $$\frac{pdf_{1}(x_{0})}{pdf_{2}(x_{0})}>\frac{p_{2}}{p_{1}}.$$  If costs of misclassification are available, choose the rule that minimizes the expected cost of misclassification. CLassify $x_{0}$ to $class_{1}$, if $$\frac{pdf_{1}(x_{0})}{pdf_{2}(x_{0})}>\frac{p_{2}C(1|2)}{p_{1}C(2|1}$$, where p_{1},p_{2}$ are prior probs, and $C(1|2)$ and $C(2|1)$ are the costs of misclassification.

Comment: The last line in the above comment should be read as *where $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ are prior probs, and $C(1|2)$ and $C(2|1)$ are the costs of misclassification*

Comment: so then max $p_{i} \cdot pdf_{i}$ or min $p_{i} \cdot pdf_{i} \cdot C(i\vert j)$